# Authentication using digital signtures

Tags: security, authentication, cryptography, digital-certificate

I know a bit of authentication theory, but would like to know how is it really put in practice.

There are these software patches that must be distributed periodically. To ensure that only the genuine content reaches our users, we have been advised to sign our content before distribution.

The plan is to generate a Public-Private key pair. The patch would first be signed by our private key and recipients then authenticate the downloaded patch by using our public key. Our idea of signing is to generate a hash of the patch and encrypt the hash with our private key. The encrypted hash (signature) is to be bundled along with the patch before distribution.

We have been advised further that it is a good practice to get a digital certificate for our public key from a CA and post it on a certificate server in our premises. We are told that the CA would create this certificate using its private key. Our users are expected to download the public key certificate from our server and authenticate it using the public key of the CA. Thus our users would be confident that they have the right public key from us to authenticate the genuineness of the patch.

And finally the question:

1. How/where can the exact public key of the CA be downloaded for authentication of the public key certificate downloaded from our server?
2. In what formats are these certificates available? Are these plain text files or XMLs or ??

Comment: Note that RSA signature generation is not the same as hashing + encryption. Signing consists of hashing, then padding for signature generation, then modular exponentiation using the private exponent. Encryption is just *padding* ***for encryption***, then modular exponentiation using the public exponent. Don't confuse the two, different padding mechanisms at the minimum.

Comment: @owlstead: Point taken. To clarify, we are basically looking for minimal/elementary authentication. In that context, an encrypted hash seems to serve our purpose.

Comment: I don't see how encrypting a hash is any easier than to use an existing standard implementation of signature generation. I would keep to the standards unless you want end up in a maintenance nightmare. Besides, encryption using a public key normally does not require any protection against side channel attacks, signature generation on the other hand does. So you may sacrifice security as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your questions in order:

1. Using a browser and SSL. In that case you rely on the certificate store already in the browser. It may be a good idea to also publish the fingerprint of your own certificate. Note that you also distribute a certificate - or certificate chain - within your software. If the software download is trusted, then you may not even need an external Certificate Authority. But in that case you keep your private key of the CA very secure.
2. X5.09 certificates are created using ASN.1 DER encoding. DER is a binary encoding (and the textual ASN.1 definitions specifies the contents). Certificates are also often distributed in PEM format. This is a base 64 encoding of the binary certificate, with an additional header and footer.

Comment: The software download is not trusted. We basically want to sensitize our users about the origins of the patch just downloaded. If it came from us, they are fine. If it came from someone else, users must then decide if they would like to proceed with installation. Our tool on user PCs which installs these patches will download our public key certificate issued by a CA. Question is how can we authenticate our own public key certificate using CA public certificate? For example Verisign provides several classes of public root certificates. How do we know which one is to be used?

Comment: Well, that's easy: *ask Verisign*. The type of certificate request you want to have signed (creating a certificate) is called a **code signing certificate**. I would urge you to use that term in communications.

Comment: So you are saying that once a request to the CA is made, it would provide the requestor with 2 keys. The firsr

Comment: Please ignore the comment above. Something is amiss. Please help me understand. You are saying that I give Verisign my public key and it gives me two certificates. The first one is the public key certificate of the public key which I shared with the CA and the second one is code signing certificate. Both certificates are in DER or PEM format. During patch authentication, I would then use code signing certificate to first authenticate the public key certificate and later authenticate the patch using the just authenticated public key certificate.

Comment: No, just one certificate. I cannot completely explain PKI here unfortunately. Please try and lookup a tutorial on that subject.